# MPMoviePlayerController plays only audio after application enters foreground

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app that plays video files stored on Amazon S3 using HTTP Live Streaming.
Sometimes when I move the app to background (press the "Home" button), return to the app and press play button, only audio is playing and a black square or the QuickTime logo is displayed instead of the video (playback controls are visible).
I don't use variant quality playlist (I have only one stream, which is video stream).

Here is the code I use to play a video on iPad (I don't use fullscreen - it's an embedded player):

```
    self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.playerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    self.playerController.contentURL = mediaURL;
    self.playerController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    self.playerController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
    self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerController.view];
    [self.playerController prepareToPlay];
```

I don't recreate the player every time the app is entering foreground or becoming active (and I'd like to avoid it).

I have exactly the same issue on iPhone (I use MPMoviePlayerViewController in fullscreen to play video there).

The application is running on iOS 6.1

Thanks,
Piotrek

Comment: check if this viewcontroller is visible currently

Comment: Yes, it is visible, otherwise I would not be able to press play.

Comment: if the code is in viewDidLoad, put it in the viewWillAppear

Comment: The code is in _viewDidLoad_ but this method is only called once - when I present the view that contains the video. Problem occurs only after returning from background (my view is not unloaded).

Comment: Did you find the soultion?